# Refreshing an Excel File using Python 3

Tags: python-3.x, excel, automation, win32com

I am new to Python and I am trying to write a function to  refresh the contents of excel files using the following code:

```
# function that refreshes files 
def refresh_file(file_to_refresh):

excel = win32com.client.Dispatch("Excel.Application")
excel.Visible = False
workbook = excel.Workbooks.Open(file_to_refresh)
workbook.RefreshAll()
workbook.Save()
excel.Quit()

refresh_file('C:\\Users\\michaelw\\Desktop\\Team Allocations\\Client Care - Liaison_dev.xlsx')
refresh_file('C:\\Users\\michaelw\\Desktop\\Team Allocations\\Client Care - ROR_dev.xlsx')
```

It works perfectly fine when when I call the function for the Client Care - Liaison_dev.xlsx file however when I call another excel file to refresh afterwards (Such as the Client Care - ROR_dev.xlsx ) I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\michaelw\Desktop\Team Allocations\Team_allocation.py", line 189, in <module>
    refresh_file('C:\\Users\\michaelw\\Desktop\\Team Allocations\\Client Care - ROR_dev.xlsx')
  File "c:\Users\michaelw\Desktop\Team Allocations\Team_allocation.py", line 120, in refresh_file
    workbook = excel.Workbooks.Open(file_to_refresh)
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\michaelw\AppData\Local\Temp\gen_py\3.11\00020813-0000-0000-C000-000000000046x0x1x9\Workbooks.py", line 75, in Open
    ret = self._oleobj_.InvokeTypes(1923, LCID, 1, (13, 0), ((8, 1), (12, 17), (12, 17), (12, 17), (12, 17), (12, 17), (12, 17), (12, 17), (12, 17), (12, 17), (12, 17), (12, 17), (12, 17), (12, 17), (12, 17)),Filename
          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
pywintypes.com_error: (-2147352567, 'Exception occurred.', (0, 'Microsoft Excel', 'Open method of Workbooks class failed', 'xlmain11.chm', 0, -2146827284), None)
```

Comment: What happens if you open the files in the opposite order ... do you still get the error on the 2nd file opened?

Comment: when I do that it attempts it gives me the same error

Comment: It appears the source files seem to be the problem

Comment: There are two things that might be going on: 1) (most likely) is that either the file you are opening doesn't exists, or it has a problem, or 2) you are running into a timing issue with create one Excel application object and then another soon after (while Excel might still be trying to process the Quit() ). Make Excel visible while you run your code: if Excel is trying to give a warning but can't display it, then it will (probably) throw an exception instead.